# Linking VS and Git. Getting error message

Tags: c#, git

[image]When I try and do a Commit I get this error message.

An error occurred. Detailed message: Could not open 'C:/Users/Nate/AppData/Local/Comms/UnistoreDB/store.vol': The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I don't understand because the local repository I set up is C:\Users\Nate\Desktop\GitRepo\NewRepo

Also after I get the error message the button is grayed out.
Everything works fine on my school computer but not on my computer.  I am using version 2015.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is Visual studio is trying to get your email address in order to initialise your git config, but, frankly, who knows, it's a black box.
Try closing all Email applications, or, create your git repository directly using the git command line.